# How to deal with unchecked call in BaseViewHolder in RecyclerView.Adpater

Tags: android, generics, android-recyclerview, generic-programming

```
public abstract class BaseViewHolder<T> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private SparseArray<View> mViews;
    private View mItemView;

    public BaseViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mItemView = itemView;
        mViews = new SparseArray<>();
    }

    public View getView(int resId) {
        View view = mViews.get(resId);

        if (view == null) {
            view = mItemView.findViewById(resId);
            mViews.put(resId, view);
        }
        return view;
    }

    public abstract void bindViewData(T data);
}

public class MultiRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder> {
    private List<TypeData> mData;
    private TypeFactory mTypeFactory;

    public MultiRecyclerAdapter(List<TypeData> data) {
        mData = data;
        mTypeFactory = new MultiTypeFactory();
    }

    public List<TypeData> getData() {
        return mData;
    }

    public void setData(List<TypeData> data) {
        mData = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(viewType, parent, false);
        return mTypeFactory.createViewHolder(viewType, view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bindViewData(mData.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mData.get(position).type(mTypeFactory);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mData != null ? mData.size() : 0);
    }

}

public interface TypeFactory {
    int type(NewsEntry.NewsDataBean newsDataBean);

    int type(EmptyBean emptyBean);

    int type(NoMoreEntity noMoreEntity);

    BaseViewHolder createViewHolder(int type, View itemView);
}

public class MultiTypeFactory implements TypeFactory {
    private final int NEWS_ITEM_LAYOUT_ID = R.layout.rv_news_item;
    private final int VIDEO_ITEM_LAYOUT_ID = R.layout.rv_video_item;
    private final int EMPTY_ITEM_LAYOUT_ID = R.layout.rv_empty_item;
    private final int NO_MORE_ITEM_LAYOUT_ID = R.layout.rv_no_more_item;

    @Override
    public int type(NewsEntry.NewsDataBean newsDataBean) {
        return NEWS_ITEM_LAYOUT_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public int type(EmptyBean emptyBean) {
        return EMPTY_ITEM_LAYOUT_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public int type(NoMoreEntity noMoreEntity) {
        return NO_MORE_ITEM_LAYOUT_ID;
    }

    @Override
    public BaseViewHolder createViewHolder(int type, View itemView) {
        switch (type) {
            case NEWS_ITEM_LAYOUT_ID:
                return new NewsViewHolder(itemView);
            case EMPTY_ITEM_LAYOUT_ID:
                return new EmptyViewHolder(itemView);
            case NO_MORE_ITEM_LAYOUT_ID:
                return new NoMoreViewHolder(itemView);
            default:
                throw new IllegalStateException("incorrect layout type");
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get rid of the warning:

> Unchecked call to 'bindViewData(T)' as a member of raw type
>   'com.kunlun.xianshi.viewholder.BaseViewHolder' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Signals places where an unchecked warning is issued by the compiler,
>   for example:
>
> void f(HashMap map) {
>       map.put("key", "value");   }    Hint: Pass -Xlint:unchecked to javac to get more details.

which is in the following code:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bindViewData(mData.get(position));
}
```

Below is how I can use it:

```
public class NewsViewHolder extends BaseViewHolder<NewsEntry.NewsDataBean> {
    public NewsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindViewData(final NewsEntry.NewsDataBean data) {

        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) getView(R.id.tv_news_title);
        TextView tvAuthor = (TextView) getView(R.id.tv_news_author);
        TextView tvDate = (TextView) getView(R.id.tv_news_date);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) getView(R.id.iv_news_pic1);


        tvTitle.setText(data.getTitle());
        tvAuthor.setText("");
        tvDate.setText(DateUtils.getDateStr(null,data.getTime()));

        String picPath = data.getCover();
        if (picPath != null) {
            RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.empty_data);
            Glide.with(itemView.getContext()).load(picPath).apply(options).into(imageView);
        } else {
            imageView.setVisibility(GONE);
        }

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClass(itemView.getContext(), WebActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("URL", data.getUrl());
                itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}



public class NewsEntry {

    public static class NewsDataBean implements TypeData {
        int id;
        private String title;
        int categoryId;
        String url;
        String cover;
        long time;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public int getCategoryId() {
            return categoryId;
        }

        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public long getTime() {
            return time;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getCover() {
            return cover;
        }

        @Override
        public int type(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
            return typeFactory.type(this);
        }
    }

    private List<NewsDataBean> news;

    public List<NewsDataBean> getNews() {
        return news;
    }
}
```

Comment: @pskink I think the gist is a little different from mine.
I have a BaseViewHolder and has the T generic,
In MultiTypeFactory, I need to create the subclass which is the specific viewholder.

Comment: It's not clear from the question what is that "map". How do you use it and what are you trying to accomplish? The function name "f" doesn't tell much.. Please make it more clear. Thanks.

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin updated